# How to connect to oracle procedure from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, oracle

My task is to connect to a stored procedure in Oracle from an asp.net page. The procedure has an output parameter of type record. I am having a problem trying to get a return value from the procedure. And I have to populate a drop down list with the return value.
Any help will be really appreciated.

What I have tried:

```
string str = "User ID=username;Password=password;Data Source=Test";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(str);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("stored_procedure_name", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_look_up_code", "varchar2").Value = "HR";
cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_filter1", "varchar2").Value = null;
cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_filter2", "varchar2").Value = null;
cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_filter3, "varchar2").Value = null;
cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_user_id", "varchar2").Value = 1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_app_code", "varchar2").Value = 1;

cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cur_list", "refcurser").Direction =      ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_error_code", "decimal").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_err_text", "varchar2").Direction = ParameterDirection.IOutput;
cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_err_text_eng", "varchar2").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();

conn.Open();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSource ds = new DataSource();
da.Fill(ds);
```